# Murmurhash3 between Java and C++ is not aligning

Tags: java, c++, murmurhash

I have 2 separate applications one in Java and the other is C++. I am using Murmurhash3 for both. However, in C++ I get a different result as compared to Java for the same string

Here is the one from C++: https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/trunk/MurmurHash3.cpp?r=144

I am using the following function:

```
void MurmurHash3_x86_32 ( const void * key, int len,
                      uint32_t seed, void * out )
```

Here is the one for Java: [http://search-hadoop.com/c/HBase:hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/MurmurHash3.java||server+void+%2522hash](http://search-hadoop.com/c/HBase%3ahbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/MurmurHash3.java||server+void+%2522hash)

There are many versions of the same Java code above.

This is how I am making a call for Java:

```
String s = new String("b2622f5e1310a0aa14b7f957fe4246fa");
System.out.println(MurmurHash3.murmurhash3_x86_32(s.getBytes(), 0, s.length(), 2147368987));
```

The output I get from Java:
-1868221715

The output I get from C++
3297211900

When I tested for some other sample strings like 
"7c6c5be91430a56187060e06fd64dcb8" and "7e7e5f2613d0a2a8c591f101fe8c7351" they match in Java and C++.

Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: I dont know much about java but I always thought its internal bytes of strings are utf16

Comment: I tried with the following:s = new String("b2622f5e1310a0aa14b7f957fe4246fa".getBytes(), "UTF-16");
  System.out.println(MurmurHash3.murmurhash3_x86_32(s.getBytes(), 0, s.length(), MURMUR_SEED)); I still see difference

Comment: you might want to output the size and single bytes you stuff into the murmur function to see if they are identical

Comment: Internally Java `String`s are UTF-16 big endian, but when you call `getBytes()` it gives you back whatever the default platform encoding is. If you haven't explicitly set it, always assume it is EBCDIC or something equally horrible, and specify an explicit encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems I can see. First, C++ is using `uint32_t`, and giving you a value of 3,297,211,900. This number is larger than can fit in a signed 32-bit int, and Java uses only signed integers. However, -1,868,221,715 is not equal to 3,297,211,900, even accounting for the difference between signed and unsigned ints.

(In Java 8 they have added `Integer.toUnsignedString(int)`, which will convert a signed 32-bit int to its unsigned string representation. In earlier versions of Java, you can cast the `int` to a `long` and then mask off the high bits: `((long) i) & 0xffffffffL`.)

The second problem is that you are using the wrong version of `getBytes()`. The one that takes no argument converts a Unicode `String` to a `byte[]` using the default platform encoding, which may vary depending on how your system is set up. It could be giving you UTF-8, Latin1, Windows-1252, KOI8-R, Shift-JIS, EBCDIC, etc.

**Never, ever, ever call the no arguments version of `String.getBytes()`, under any circumstances. It should be deprecated, decimated, defenestrated, destroyed, and deleted.**

Use `s.getBytes("UTF-8")` (or whatever encoding you're expecting to get) instead.

As the *Zen of Python* says, "Explicit is better than implicit."

I can't tell if there may be any other problems beyond these two.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with you. But the Java version of my Murmurhash3 is different from yours. After making some changes to the C++ version of Murmurhash3, I made the hash values generated from the two versions the same. I give you my solution, which you can use to check if it also works for you.
Maybe the biggest difference between the Java and C++ versions lies in the **right shift operation(in Java you can see >> and >>>, while in C++ you can only see >>)**. The integers in Java are all signed, while in C++ you can use signed or unsigned integers. In Java version, the **>>** means arithmetic right shift and the **>>>** means logical right shift. And in C++, the **>>** means arithmetic right shift. The original C++ version of Murmurhash3 uses unsigned integer, and in order to generate the negative hash value like in Java, **first** in C++ you should change all the unsigned type **uint32_t** to signed type **int32_t**. **Then** you should locate the **>>>** in Java and make changes around the corresponding **>>** in C++. For me, **I change from：**

```
inline uint32_t rotl32 ( uint32_t x, int8_t r )
{
  return (x << r) | (x >> (32 - r));
}
```

**to:**

```
inline int32_t rotl32 ( int32_t x, int8_t r )
{
  return (x << r) | (int32_t)((uint32_t)x >> (32 - r)); //similar to >>> in Java
}
```

**and from:**

```
FORCE_INLINE uint32_t fmix32 ( uint32_t h )
{
  h ^= h >> 16;
  h *= 0x85ebca6b;
  h ^= h >> 13;
  h *= 0xc2b2ae35;
  h ^= h >> 16;

  return h;
}
```

**to:**

```
FORCE_INLINE int32_t fmix32 ( int32_t h )
{
  h ^= (int32_t)((uint32_t)h >> 16); // similar to >>> in Java
  h *= 0x85ebca6b;
  h ^= (int32_t)((uint32_t)h >> 13);
  h *= 0xc2b2ae35;
  h ^= (int32_t)((uint32_t)h >> 16);

  return h;
}
```

In this way, my two versions of Murmurhash3 in Java and C++ generate the same hash value.

Comment: How can I solve this problem in java code without changing C++ code?